# wkhtmltopdf issue with specific Wingdings character

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wingdings

I am facing issue with Wingdings character. Few unicode characters are not coming properly in the PDF output. Below two characters are present in Wingdings font, but it is not coming when I use wkhtmltopdf.

ý   U+00FD
þ   U+00FE

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Last time I looked at the Wingdings font, it was not a Unicode font. That page referenced specifically warns you *not* to use them in Web pages and wkhtmltopdf is a wrapped web browser.

Comment: These characters are converted exactly in WKHTMLTOPDF Windows, but not in Unix. In Unix, these two characters are not able to recognized.

Comment: Have you installed the font in Unix?